# SQL Anywhere file structure

Tags: file-format

Where can I find the file structure of a (non-encrypted) Sybase SQL anywhere portable database (for data recovery purposes).

I'm aware of some tools that can do it, but I would like to build my own tool.

Comment: I think what other people might be hinting, is that they may be able to help better if you listed the tools you already know, and why you think they are insufficient for your needs

Answer (score -2):

While this question is really bad for a StackExchange, nor have you shown any afford yourself. Here are the things you could do:

1. Reverse the File Structure
2. Reverse Engineer an tool you are aware of that does the same.
3. Find a document that explains how this works.